# How can I search an array for specific values?

Tags: php

I need some help with how I can search an array from a search box.

Lets say I search for the `$ticker` and write `BTC`

It will then print out:

```
The last known currency for BTC is 57
```

I only want it to print out $k3 values.

Appreciate if you could take your time and guide me in the right direction :)

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="Searcharray" name="searcharray">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" name="searcharray">
</form>

<?php

$ticker = array(
    0 => "BTC",
    1 => "ETH",
    2 => "LTC",
    3 => "XMR",
    4 => "XRP"
);
$name = array(
    0 => "Bitcoin",
    1 => "Ethereum",
    2 => "Litecoin",
    3 => "Monero",
    4 => "Ripple"
);
$k1 = array(
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
    3 => 4,
    4 => 5
);
$k2 = array(
    0 => 11,
    1 => 12,
    2 => 13,
    3 => 14,
    4 => 15
);
$k3 = array(
    0 => 17,
    1 => 27,
    2 => 37,
    3 => 47,
    4 => 57
);
?>
```

Comment: what is the relation except sequence ?

Comment: Why do you put everything in different arrays, instead of using a 2-dimensional array?

Comment: Use `array_search()` to find the index of `BTC` in `$ticker`. Then use that index to get the price from `$k3`. What's the problem?

Comment: You may find a database more helpful here than fixed arrays ...

Comment: Where is your attempt? I just see a form and an array.

Comment: Why is the answer for BTC 57 instead of 17?

Answer (score 0):

array_search would help - http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-search.php

```
$index = array_search('BTC', $ticker);
$value = $k3[$index];
```

Why dont you make such a structure?:

```
$data = [
  'BTC' => [
     'name' => 'Bitcoin',
     'k1' => 1,
     'k2' => 11,
     'k3' => 17
  ], ...
];
```

then it would be:

```
$value = $data['BTC']['k3'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$index = array_search("BTC", $ticker);
if ($index !== FALSE) {
    $currency = $k3[$index];
    echo "The last known currency of BTC is $currency";
}
```

But things would be easier if you used a 2-dimensional associative array:

```
$data = [
    "BTC" => ["name" => "Bitcoin", "k1" => 1, "k2" => 11, "k3" => 17],
    "ETH" => ["name" => "Ethereum", "k1" => 2, "k2" => 12, "k3" => 27],
    ...
];
```

Then you can do:

```
if (isset($data["BTC"])) {
    $currency = $data["BTC"]["k3"];
    echo "The last known currency of BTC is $currency";
}
```

Comment: Okay, ill look into it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're right in everything that you say here, however OP wanted to get the value `57`, which appears to be the last element in the `$k3` array. I'm not sure how these arrays link together... Perhaps if @kabakka gives us more clues on how you get the last element of `$k3` from the search of `$ticker`, do we need to `array_reverse($k3)`?